# Socat serial to tcp for authorized users

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi, socket, socat, unix-sockets

Hello everyone I hope you doing well
I have a raspberry pi and I kind need a serial port server which can access from internet
Now I use socat command like bellow on my raspberry and from putty on another device with telnet protocol it worked on local network

```
socat -d -d -d -d tcp4-l:9993,reuseaddr,fork /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,ignoreeof=0,nonblock=1
```

But as far as I know everyone who has IP address and the port could access to serial port and it's not good for a server on internet

But I just need to only authorized users can access to this port so how can I define username and password for reaching to this port

Comment: Have you tried using CWproxyauth?  Are you trying to avoid shared users?  Please provide your use case for more functionality or what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Actually I have a online server (rpi) and by the time only one user can access to the telnet port. Now in regular mode it's ok. But for security reasons access to this port should need username and password. And yes I did use proxyauth but I don't now how to connect to it . "socat -d -d -d -d tcp4-l:9993,reuseaddr,fork /dev/ttyUSB0,raw, proxyauth=user,pass"